# How to add a new row to existing table in HTML

Tags: c#, html, mysql, asp.net, .net

Here is my ASP code to display a database table in the form of HTML table

```
if (operation == "display"){
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("select StudentId, StudentName from tblStudent where StudentStatus = 'a'", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    Response.Write("<Table cellpadding = 5>");
    Response.Write("<tr>");
    Response.Write("<th>");
    Response.Write("Student Id");
    Response.Write("</th>");
    Response.Write("<th>");
    Response.Write("Student Name");
    Response.Write("</th>");
    Response.Write("</tr>");
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows){
       Response.Write("<tr>");
       Response.Write("<td>");
       Response.Write(dr["StudentId"].ToString());
       Response.Write("</td>");
       Response.Write("<td>");
       Response.Write(dr["studentName"].ToString());
       Response.Write("</td>");
       Response.Write("</tr>");
   }
   Response.Write("</Table>");
}
```

Here's my insert code:

```
if (operation == "insert"){
    string sid, sname;
    sid = Request.QueryString["StudentId"].ToString();
    sname = Request.QueryString["StudentName"].ToString();
    //MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("insert into tblStudent (StudentId, StudentName) values (sid, sname)", con);
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblStudent (StudentId, StudentName) values('" + sid.ToString() + "', '" + sname.ToString() + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
}
```

It's working perfectly. But I don't want to read whole table again when I perform insert operation. I just want to append the row to HTML table which is defined in display method when cmd.ExecuteNonQuery returns 1 (To make sure that the database table got updated). How?

Comment: if you don't want to reload whole data you should make insert operation in client side.

Comment: Use parameterized queries to avoid SQL injection attack

Comment: Everything is happening in ajax and there is no point of reload @NumanKIZILIRMAK

Comment: This is just a testdb and I am on experiment spree @SankarRaj

Comment: How are you calling your insert method? By Jquery then after success append a new row in the table.

Comment: Using ajax @शेखर

Comment: add that code in your question. Because at the same place you need to change.

Answer (score 0):

in your ajax succeess callback append new row to table

```
succcess:function(data)
{
    var newRow= "";                   
    newRow= newRow+ "<tr>";
    newRow= newRow+ "<td>" + studentId + "</td>";
    newRow= newRow+ "<td>" + studentName + "</td>";      
    newRow= newRow+ "</tr>";                        
    $('.yourtable').append(newRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create HTML table as server side control using runat='server'.
So your table creation part will be as below;

```
**Response.Write("<Table runat='server' id='tblStudents' cellpadding = 5>");**
```

After Saving, you can access this control from code behind and add rows.
Add below code after successful insertion;

```
var row= new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableRow();
var cellSID = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
cellSID.InnerText = sid;
row.Cells.Add(cellSID);

 var cellSName = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTableCell();
 cellSID.InnerText = sname;
 row.Cells.Add(cellSName);

 tblStudents.Rows.Insert(0, row);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this way using jquery's `append`. It will append row after finding last child within the `tbody` of your `table`:

```
$('#yourTableID > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>Some Data</td>...</tr>');
```

**Note: Table should have at least one `row` for this to work which you can easily do by counting the rows within your table using jquery.**